# GCP Kuberentes Cloud Deploy vs Cloud build

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, skaffold

I am deploying a kubernetes app via github on GCP clusters. Everything works fine  then.. I came across `cloud deploy delivery pipeline`..now I am stuck.

Following the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/deploy/docs/quickstart-basic?_ga=2.141149938.-1343950568.1631260475&_gac=1.47309141.1631868766.CjwKCAjw-ZCKBhBkEiwAM4qfF2mz0qQw_k68XtDo-SSlglr1_U2xTUO0C2ZF8zBOdMlnf_gQVwDi3xoCQ8IQAvD_BwE) here

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta12
kind: Config
build:
  artifacts:
  - image: skaffold-example
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - k8s-*
```

In the `k8s` folder I have my deployment files like so

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ixh-auth-depl
  labels:
    app: ixh-auth
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ixh-auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ixh-auth
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ixh-auth
        image: mb/ixh-auth:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 500Mi
```

but it gives the error `invalid kubernetes manifest`. I cannot find anything to read on this and don't know how to proceed.

Comment: To troubleshoot,change your skaffold.yaml file to include the manifest files in your folder one by one instead of `k8s-*' or apply divide and conquer to find out which is the offending file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to declare the manifests was this. The wildcard probably didn't work. The folder name here would be `k8s-manifests`.

```
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - k8s-manifests/redis-deployment.yml
      - k8s-manifests/node-depl.yml
      - k8s-manifests/node-service.yml
```

Comment: Using `k8s-manifests/*` should work: on Unix, a directory is a file, but the contents won't be YAML.  I've opened the following issue to improve the error message https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/issues/6641

Answer (score 1):

@Abhishek Rai,  I agree with your answer. Google Cloud Deploy uses **skaffold render** to render your Kubernetes manifests, replacing untagged image names with the tagged image names of the container images you're deploying. Then when you promote the release, Google Cloud Deploy uses skaffold apply to apply the manifests and deploy the images to your Google Kubernetes Engine cluster.The content of manifest files should include the path of the yaml files as

```
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - PATH_TO_MANIFEST
```

so that the error will not be encountered. Refer to the [document](https://cloud.google.com/deploy/docs/skaffold)  for more details.